# Mixed chart scatter plot with chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a scatter-plot chart in chart.js mixing a line chart and a bubble chart to graph the dispersion of some data vs the "ideal" of a predictive math model.

I'm using the `scales` to scatter the `xAxes` and make a straight line (which represents the "ideal"). The problem is in the bubble chart, the data of bubble can't be exactly over the line, is technically impossible (in theory), but they are exactly over the "ideal" line.

Here is my example code for the chart:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: {
      labels: makeLabels().labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          label: 'Data',
          data: makeLabels().labels,
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(218,83,79, .7)",
          borderColor: "rgba(218,83,79, .7)",
          pointRadius: 0
        },
        {
          type: 'bubble',
          label: 'Data2',
          data: makeBubbles(),
          backgroundColor: "rgba(76,78,80, .7)",
          borderColor: "transparent"
        }
      ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: Math.max(...makeLabels().array)
        }
     }]
    }
  }
});
```

And [here is the complete code](http://codepen.io/nanotime/pen/QpMOJR) with the dummie data and the playground in codepen.

Anyway, this is the actual result:

[image]

And this is the expected result:

[image]

The position of the line is irrelevant (the charts in the captures aren't plotted with the same data), but what i want is to cause the bubbles to disperse.

¿Any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your points are coming out linearly is because you are setting each data point's x and y value to be the same in `makeBubbles()`.  This results in points that are positioned linearly.

To get the points to scatter just use point that don't fall into a linear pattern.  To demonstrate what I mean, I have modified your `makeBubbles()` function so that your x and y values aren't equal.  Now you get a very broad scatter.

```
arr = arr.map(function(item, i) {
  return {x: item, y:arr[i - 1]}
});
```

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpObKo).